# "Had to say" vs. "said"

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

As described in the title, I want to know the difference between those expressions.

E.g.:

> Let's hear **what he had to say** about ...

vs.

> Let's hear **what he said** about...

Thank you.

Comment: the term "let's" don´t mean something that's about to happen? In this example you gave, I think it would be more suitable to write:
"Let's hear what he have to say about.."

Comment: @FernandoVieira - "Let's hear what he have to say" is not grammatically correct.  It would be **what he has to say** or **what he had to say**.  (Or **what he said**, as the original poster said.)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right @stangdon. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

"Had to " in the first sentence has nothing to do with modality in this context. "Had" is used as "possessed ".

> Have you got anything to say?

The sentence means "Let's hear what he prepared to say", or "let's hear his opinion". 
The second sentence refers to what he said.

Comment: The difference between "had to say" and "said" is quite subtle in my opinion, but overall I agree with this analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There is an emotive difference between the two. **Had to say** implies an urgency, a need to express or explain something, or an obligation to say something:

> I **had to say** something to make the dog attack stop.
>   He did not understand, so I **had to say** that it's not possible.
>   He **had to say** he was a refugee before entering the country.

**Said** is a more neutral, and possibly more ambiguous in terms of urgency:

> He **said** he was tired, and went to bed.
>   She **said** it was raining yesterday.

Comment: I have to disagree with you on the usage of **had to say**; it does not imply any urgency in this native speaker's opinion.  Consider this example: *"We asked Senator Bloggs about the healthcare bill, and this is what he had to say."*  It only means "possessed" in this context.  I agree that this can be confusing and ambiguous, because "have to" can mean necessity or urgency, as in "I have to leave", but not in this context.

Comment: @stangdon, fair point, "These are my thoughts on" = "This is what I have to say about"

Comment: @stangdon, I agree with you. I was wondering if "have" here means "possess ".By the way, it's just the same in other languages. Like in" Have you got anything to say?" anything =what,  meaning someone 's opinion.